# Deep Q Network gives same Q values and doesn't improve

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to build a deep Q network to play snake. I've run into an issue where the agent doesn't learn and its performance at the end of the training cycle is to repeatedly kill itself. After a bit of debugging, I figured out that the Q values the network predicts are the same every time. The action space is [up, right, down, left] and the network predicts [0, 0, 1, 0]. The training loss does go down over time, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Here's the training code:

```
def train(self):
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
    self.build_model()
    for episode in range(self.max_episodes):
        self.current_episode = episode
        env = SnakeEnv(self.screen)
        episode_reward = 0
        for timestep in range(self.max_steps):
            env.render(self.screen)
            state = self.screenshot()
            #state = env.get_state()
            action = None
            epsilon = self.current_eps
            if epsilon > random.random():
                action = np.random.choice(env.action_space) #explore
            else:
                values = self.policy_model.predict(state) #exploit
                action = np.argmax(values)
            experience = env.step(action)
            if(experience['done'] == True):
                episode_reward += experience['reward']
                break
            episode_reward += experience['reward']
            self.push_memory(Experience(experience['state'], experience['action'], experience['reward'], experience['next_state']))
            self.decay_epsilon(episode)
            if self.can_sample_memory():
                memory_sample = self.sample_memory()
                X = []
                Y = []
                for memory in memory_sample:
                    memstate = memory.state
                    action = memory.action
                    next_state = memory.next_state
                    reward = memory.reward
                    max_q = reward + (self.discount_rate * self.replay_model.predict(next_state)) #bellman equation
                    X.append(memstate)
                    Y.append(max_q)
                X = np.array(X)
                X = X.reshape([-1, 600, 600, 2])
                Y = np.array(Y)
                Y = Y.reshape([self.batch_size, 4])
                self.policy_model.fit(X, Y)
        food_eaten = experience["food_eaten"]
        print("Episode: ", episode, " Total Reward: ", episode_reward, " Food Eaten: ", food_eaten)
        if episode % self.target_update == 0:
            self.replay_model.set_weights(self.policy_model.get_weights())
    self.policy_model.save_weights('weights.hdf5')
    pygame.quit()
```

Here's the network architecture:

```
    self.policy_model = Sequential()
    self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', data_format = "channels_last", input_shape = (600, 600, 2)))
    self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    self.policy_model.add(Flatten())
    self.policy_model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
    self.policy_model.add(Dense(5, activation = "softmax"))
    rms = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr = self.learning_rate) 
    self.policy_model.compile(optimizer = rms, loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

Here are the hyperparameters:

```
learning_rate = 1e-4
discount_rate = 0.99
eps_start = 1
eps_end = .01
eps_decay = 1e-5
memory_size = 100000
batch_size = 2
max_episodes = 1000
max_steps = 100000
target_update = 100
```

I've let it train for the full 1000 episodes and it's pretty bad at the end. Am I doing something wrong with the training algorithm?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the agent receives a reward of 0.5 for going towards the food, 1 for eating the food, and -1 for dying

EDIT 2: Just read that some DQNs use a stack of 4 consecutive frames as a single sample. Would this be necessary to implement for my environment, considering how simple movements are?

Answer (score 2):

Reinforcement learning algorithms need a very low optimizer learning rate (e.g. 1.e-4 or below) in order not to learn too fast and overfit on a subspace of the environment (looks like your problem). Here you seem to use the default learning rate of your optimizer (rmsprop, which is 0.001 by default).

Anyway, this could be a possible reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to epsilon decay. It sets the exploration exploration trade-off over time. If your epsilon decay is too big, it will start to exploit a very small (unexplored) space of the state action space. 
Most of the time with me, at least, early convergence in bad policy was caused by too big epsilon decay.